# Way to return the name with an element in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Beginner in Java, I look for the way to return with my function "readPeople ()" the name associated in my ArrayList "this.list" thanks to id given by the user.
Here is my code:

```
public class PersonneC implements PersonneDB {
    this.list = new ArrayList();

    People marie = new People(1, "Bower", "Marie");
    list.add(marie.toString());

      public PeopleWithId readPeople(int idPeople) {
        PeopleWithId peoplename = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(liste.get(i).equals(idPeople)) {
                result = list.get(i);
            }
        }
        return result.getPeopleName(); //ERROR INCOMPATIBLE TYPES
        }
```

> Wanted result returned: Bower

Comment: can we have People class and what type is result i think is People and check your list.add(marie.toString())

Comment: `getPeopleName()` returns probably a `String` but your method declares `PeopleWithId` as return type. It is not compatible. Change it as      `public String readPeople(int idPeople) `

Comment: aside from the compiler error, it would be more efficient to  replace `result = list.get(i);` with `return list.get(i);` then after the `for` loop return `null` or even better use an `Optional<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<People> list = new ArrayList<>();

// add people to the list
People marie = new People(1, "Bower", "Marie");
list.add(marie);

// Search function
  public String readPeople(int idPeople) {
    People p = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        // If equal than it is the result
        if(list.get(i).id == idPeople) {
            p = list.get(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return p == null ? null : p.getName();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
However, I am told on the line "if(list.get(i).id == idPeople) {" at the index "id" the following error "Can not resolve symbol id", why ?

Comment: Maybe your id is private or protected or you named your property some else.

Comment: And you can see I add People object to the array not String.

Comment: Thank you very ! in fact I forgot to add the object to the array... beginner error (y)

Answer (score 2):

Your method returns a `string`, and the return type of the `readPeople` is `PeopleWithId`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting incompatible types is because in your function readPeople you have told it to return PeopleWithId, where you are returning a string.

After the public modifier change PeopleWithId because this object doesn't exist, change it to a String. What this does is tell the function of the type of object you want to get from it, in this case a String because you're name has been stored as a String.